# What response should be send to zapier if not get any desired data to send from my server to zapier

Tags: node.js, response, zapier

I want to send some data from my server to zapier which is requested by the zapier. What to send in response if my server does not have that data. It should be empty array response or some error message

```
if(contact?.length){
  const contactClone = _.clone(contact);
   _.filter(contactClone, function(o: any) { return o.tag_updated_on; });  // if some specific contact has this field which should be rerturned
   _.orderBy(contactClone, 'tag_updated_on', 'desc'); 
  if(contactClone?.length){
    res.status(200).json([contactClone[0]]); ////First one contact from the array would be returned
    return;
  }
  
  
  res.status(200).json([contact[0]]); //What should be returned here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should be empty array response or some error message

Either of these would be appropriate, depending on how you want the caller to respond. A 404 response would be fine if you want it to error. A `[]` or `{}` could make sense too, if the caller is expecting to handle it.